# Mongoose result.toObject keep Schema methods

Tags: node.js, function, mongoose

Because I cannot edit properties of a non-lean mongoose result, I've used the `result.toObject()` statement, but that also means I cannot use the methods defined on my Schema.

Example

```
// Defining the schema and document methods
const User = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    firstname: {type: String, required: true},
    registration_date: {type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true},
    insert: {type: String},
    lastname: {type: String, required: true}
});

User.methods.whatIsYourFirstName = function () {
    return `Hello, my firstname is:${this.firstname}`;
};
```

After a find:

```
user = user.toObject();
user.registration_date = moment(user.registration_date);
user.whatIsYourFirstName(); 
// result in "user.whatIsYourFirstName is not a function"
```

Is this solvable?

Comment: The original code has a property called `registration_date` and that value is overwritten by a momentjs value.
Earlier on in the express routes I need those methods for middleware validation, after that it's called toObject, but a few specific routes need those extra methods that are cast away when `.toObject()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Methods and Models are part of Mongoose, not MongoDB.

Whenever you are calling `.toObject()` you are being returned an object which is [ready for storage in MongoDB](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject).

If you do need to do any sort of value transformation, I'd do it just before you deliver the value to the user. Being a time formatting, if you are building an API, I'd do that in the client; if you are working with templates try transforming the value on the same template.

Comment: Not entirely what I was hoping for, but I have updated the project to this new style. Thanks :)